# Collinearity of points

Tags: geometry

Let ABC be an arbitrary triangle, and P, Q, R be the intersections of the tangent lines to circumcicles at the vertices with the extensions of respective opposite sides. Show that P, Q, R are colinears.

[image]

Here is an [interactive applet](http://www.geogebratube.org/student/m119382), thanks to Geogebra's amazing super-powers.

Comment: Picture or it did not happen.

Comment: What are circumcircles at the vertices?

Comment: To the circumcicle at the vertices. Sorry i don't speak english

Comment: If you write the statement in Spanish, I am sure someone will translate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case of [Pascal's hexagon theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_theorem) in which the six points are in fact only three (and the segment «from one point to itself» is the tangent to the conic)